# Cocoapods frameworks does not support provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, cocoapods, alamofire

I am new in iOS development world.

I am working in a iOS app development. I am using Cocoapods to integrate third party libraries like Alamofire and KeychainSwift.

When I am export my Archive to generate the .ipa file from local, its working fine. But when I am trying to do the same in my CI tool(Jenkins), its giving Export Failed!.

Its giving the error:

> exportArchive: KeychainSwift.framework does not support provisioning profiles.
> error: exportArchive: Alamofire.framework does not support provisioning profiles.

Its asking me to:

> "Remove this item from the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list."

But I will not be able to do that because it requires for my main app.

I did all the tricks over the Internet as below. I added the below line in at the end of the Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
      end
  end
end
```

After doing this I have reinstall the pods again, but no luck.

**Can anyone please help?**

Comment: what was your fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problems as you recently.It took me a few days, and then I solved it.
I use the .sh command file to package.

Only xcodebuild archive was modified:
PROVISIONING_PROFILE**_APP**="${provisioningProfile}" PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER**_APP**="${bundleID}"

Important things repeating 3 times：
(Only added : _APP)
(Only added : _APP)
(Only added : _APP)
It was finally solved.